# Reduce PDF size when merge documents with same fonts, resources

Tags: pdfbox

Does pdfbox have a feature to extract same resources, eg: fonts, images into object references when merge PDF? I cant seem to find any feature to reduce size in the docs?

I might be missing the function name in the docs. from similar products

iText
PdfSmartCopy
https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/itext-2.1.7/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfSmartCopy.html

PDFNet ( pdfTron )
Optimizer
https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFNet/html/T_pdftron_PDF_Optimizer.htm

Comment: No there is no such feature and we're not planning to do it.

Comment: I am checking in from 2020 to see if that had been reconsidered.  I have a report that is created from HTML with up to 8 images on each page.  The report can be thousands of pages and this, using html converter and merge creates files over 600 MG.  The same report generated in Crystal may be 4 MG.  This one issue is having me reconsider this approach and overall I love mine vs Crystal Reports.  Since there can be repeating images in merged files, indexing them seems like a viable option for a great product.

Answer (score 0):

Answered via comment! - there is no feature provided